# Cannot record on 1920x1080 using Android MediaRecorder on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: android, mediarecorder

List of supported Video Sizes using -

```
camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes()
```

--

```
0 - 1280 x 720

1 - 1920 x 1080

2 - 960 x 720

3 - 720 x 480

4 - 640 x 480

5 - 352 x 288

6 - 320 x 240

7 - 177 x 144
```

--
List of supported Preview Sizes using -

```
camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

--

```
0 - 960 x 720

1 - 1280 x 720

2 - 640 x 480

3 - 352 x 288

4 - 320 x 240
```

--
As we can see that the device does support recording at resolution "1920 x 1080"
However it's possible to record MP4 videos in all other resolutions except this particular one.
Samsung's default Camera app can easily record at this resolution. So why I can't do that?
Is it related to the preview size?

### This is the code I am using to configure the MediaRecorder-

```
camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
camera.unlock();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1920, 1080);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/storage/emulated/temp/test.mp4");
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
mediaRecorder.prepare();
```

--
Calling `mediaRecorder.start()` gives error -19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I used-

```
CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
```

Hopefully this helps anyone!